# How do I change the LightDM unity-greeter wallpaper behavior?

Tags: unity, login, multiple-monitors, lightdm, desktop-background

Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64

This is not how to change the login screen wallpaper, or how to stop dynamic wallpaper switching.

This is how to set the default behavior from "Scale" (or whatever the current behavior is) to "Span" to accommodate my abnormal monitor setup. (ultrawide monitor in horizontal, 1080p in vertical).

I've referenced: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Configuration and the example at **/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz**
but there is no mention of this behavior.

[image: Desired settings]

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about, exactly.

[image: What I mean]

Comment: It was not possible to change your screen background while preparing the pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Go to google images

Type the name of your favorite image ---> click search ---> click search tools ---> click size ---> click exact size

[image]

In the new window that opens type the exact size of your monitor ---> Click go

[image]

In the search result that appears download your favorite one

By default it gets saved to Pictures folder

Open terminal and type

```
sudo su
cd /home/your-username/Pictures
mv your-image.png /usr/share/backgrounds/your-image.png
## if your image extension is not png then replace png with your extension
apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

in the new window that appears go to

----> com

---> canonical

---> unity

---> unity-greeter

[image]

Go to the line with background and change the image name in the line

/usr/share/backgrounds/image-name.png

to your image name

/usr/share/backgrounds/your-image.png

Now reboot

Hopefully all will work fine now

Have a happy experience with ubuntu

Comment: This solution does not change the behavior of the wallpaper. The default behavior is to "Zoom" on each screen. For a wallpaper designed for the "Span" behavior on a vertical screen, the image would appear very zoomed in, and a horizontal screen would be zoomed out.

Comment: A visual example is listed here: [On my site](https://pappad.info/images/diff.png)